# mysql Using INNER JOIN to select multiple tables?

Tags: mysql, select, inner-join

I want to select all fields of several table and fetch result separate but mysql return all rows together:

```
SELECT prod_product.*
  ,pub_comment.* 
FROM prod_product 
INNER JOIN pub_comment ON (prod_product.id = pub_comment.itemId) 
WHERE prod_product.id=7744
```

Is there any way that i could fetch each table rows separately?

I try `@prod:=prod_product.*`, `@comment:=pub_comment.*` but mysql didn't allow me to store more than 1 row.

Comment: @user703617: remember to accept correct answer if you find one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT @prod:= CONCAT_WS(',',prod_product.field1,prod_product.field2,...)
  ,@comment:= CONCAT_WS(' ',pub_comment.field1,pub_comment.field2,....) 
FROM prod_product 
INNER JOIN pub_comment ON (prod_product.id = pub_comment.itemId) 
WHERE prod_product.id = 7744
```

Note that [CONCAT_WS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws) will separate your fields and [CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) will just smash then together.

Comment: Oh, I must warn you about concat_ws, it gave me a nasty collation error where the table was in LATIN1 and the system is set to UTF8 then the result will be in UTF8, which will not be INSERTed into a LATIN1 table. If you get this workaround is to use CONCAT(field1,' ',field2,' '...).

Answer (score 1):

Execute two queries:

```
select * from prod_product WHERE prod_product.id=7744
```

and

```
select * from pub_comment WHERE pub_comment.itemId=7744
```

A single query **always** return single rows containing two table fields.
Anyway: what is the problem of having columns together in a single row? If you have problems with their names you can use aliases.

Comment: Hi marco , Thanks for your answer but it's 2 queries and i need to decrease my db fetches, maybe i have to do it

Comment: @user703617: As I told you, why can't you use a single query? Which is the problem of having columns together?

Comment: @user703617: if you give us some detail, we can help you better :)